# Maximum number of apps that can manually deploy to Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have windows dev account and so I registered my WP device Nokia Lumia 710 in windows dev center to test my apps I currently building... I have Windows Phone sdk 7.1. there were some sites that you can directly download xap files of known Applications that is free in Windows phone App store. Due to high rates in Mobile GPRS (300Mb for 1 US$ in Sri Lanka and it quietly high in here) I decided to download apps manually and deploy it using "Application Deployment" in Windows Phone sdk.

I could deploy round 10 apps to my device, but after that is giving me a error saying "The maximum number of developer applications on this phone has been reached" as a solution it suggest to remove a developer app and try again.

What's the reason for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is to prevent what you're doing. When unlocking a phone, you're supposed to deploy only applications you've developed. In which case it is unlikely to reach the 10 apps limitation.

Now, you could argue that deploying free apps doesn't harm anyone, and I agree (except that you don't get the automatic updates). But if you can deploy free apps, you can also deploy paid apps. So I believe it's primarily to prevent piracy that Microsoft has enforced that limit.

By the way, if you want to avoid using your mobile plan, you can download and install apps directly from a desktop PC by using Zune. That way, you're still using the Marketplace, and  the number of deployed apps isn't limited.

Comment: I agree with this, but As I said we can't download apps in marketplace from Desktop and then install it to phone using zune, it costs me to download apps from phone rather than from my machine.

Comment: Installing apps from Zune... how.... can you tell me in details

Comment: @Zeemaan Looks like Microsoft has removed the Marketplace from the Zune client, I forgot about that. There may be ways to bring it back (http://www.wpcentral.com/bring-back-windows-phone-marketplace-zune-simple-registry-addition) but I've never tried it. Anyway, it's getting off-topic, you may want to ask your question here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it's not working now... I think they removed it.